# How do I use AFNetworking/AFOauth2Client with the Imgur API? I simply want to be able to get image information, no logging in

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, afnetworking, imgur

I'm interested in integrating the [Imgur API](http://api.imgur.com) into my app, and it states that in order to get image information (basically the extent of what I need right now) I [just need to register my app](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints), no need to log in with user information or anything.

Great, I'm using [AFOAuth2Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client) (specifically [this pull request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55) so it works with AFNetworking 2.0). I have my client key and client secret, but I can't seem to figure out how to get to an image.

I try the following code (personal API details removed):

```
AFOAuth2Client *oauthClient = [AFOAuth2Client clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.imgur.com/"] clientID:@"---" secret:@"---"];

[oauthClient authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize" parameters:nil success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
     NSLog(@"Yes");
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"No");
}];
```

But I always get `No` outputted. How do I properly authenticate so I can then make calls to the API to get information about an image? (As detailed [here](https://api.imgur.com/models/image).)

---

As I've been told I don't need OAuth period, I tried the following with AFNetworking 2.0 (to no avail):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[operationManager POST:@"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/1Nf1quS" parameters:@{@"Authorization": @"Client-ID myactualclientidisremoved"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the example is using Imgur API v2 which is old and unsupported. You should be using API v3.

Also note that:

For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image info, looking up user comments, etc. all you need to do is send an authorization header with your client_id in your requests.

from docs at https://api.imgur.com/oauth2 -- so you don't really need OAuth for what you're doing.

There is some example Imgur API code that might help you, listed at https://api.imgur.com/ -- the Android example might be more relevant to you, since it uses Java, but unsurprisingly it comes with all the overhead of an Android project, compared with a plain Java application.

Comment: Hmm, I read a bit of the Android application and then per your advice just used plain AFNetworking 2.0 and attached the example to the above post, but it still always returns "failure". Am I using it correctly?